# .Net framework Asynchronous ActionFilterAttribute receives wrong claims principal

Tags: asp.net, .net

We have an Action filter attribute in .net framework 4.8 that add some claims to the principal. Since we made this filter asynchronous, we see that some times the user in the principal does not match the user that initiated the request (we know this by the user id in the url).

Initially we had something like:

```
public class TenantSecurityFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken){

       //here we have tried HttpContext.Current.User and actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
          var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal; 

          var someDbData = await getSomeDbData();
          addOurClaims(principal, someDbData);

          await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }

        private void addOurClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal, someDbData){
           //add some claims
          ...

        }

    }
```

Then we found [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) where it's said that we should be setting the principal in both
HttpContext and Thread.CurrentPrincipal, so we updated our addOurClaims to do so:

```
       private void addOurClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal, someDbData){
           //add some claims
          ...

          Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
          if (HttpContext.Current != null)
          {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
          }
        }
```

Most of the requests coming through are fine, but after adding some logs we see that for a handful of them, at the very top of OnActionExecutingAsync, the user in the ClaimsPrincipal object does not match the id of the user that has initiated the request.

We no longer know where the issue is coming from and what's the best approach to manipulate claims in the action filter. Is it perhaps that .net framework does not guarantee the principal to be reliable on async action filters?

Answer (score 0):

In asynchronous action filters that manipulate the ClaimsPrincipal, need to ensure that you set the principal correctly and consistently.

- In synchronous code within your action filter, use
  HttpContext.Current.User to set and manipulate the ClaimsPrincipal.
- Use Async Local for Asynchronous Code to set and manipulate the
  ClaimsPrincipal.

```
    public class TenantSecurityFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        
                // Set and manipulate the ClaimsPrincipal asynchronously using Async Local.
                AsyncLocal<ClaimsPrincipal> asyncLocalPrincipal = new AsyncLocal<ClaimsPrincipal>();
                asyncLocalPrincipal.Value = principal;
        
                var someDbData = await getSomeDbData();
                addOurClaims(asyncLocalPrincipal.Value, someDbData);
        
                // Optionally, set the ClaimsPrincipal back to Thread.CurrentPrincipal for consistency.
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = asyncLocalPrincipal.Value;
        
                await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
            }
        
            private void addOurClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal, someDbData)
            {
                // Add your claims to the principal.
                // ...
        
                // No need to set Thread.CurrentPrincipal or HttpContext.Current.User here.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll give this a try. Wouldn't it be safer to manipulate the principal getting/setting it  in the actionContext?